# Itextsharp table not drawing lines in c#?

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to append data from a csv file in a specific format to a pdf file. The problem is that I have been successfully able to append the data but for some reason the lines between the table rows are not being drawn in my pdf document. I am really lost as I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

This is what I tried so far :-

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using Excel;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project
{

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int y;
        string[] res = null;

        public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            button1.Text = "You clicked me";
            DPdfView v = new DPdfView();
            res = v.ReadCSV().ToArray();
            generatepdffile(res);


        }

        protected void generatepdffile(string[] res)
        {

            Document doc = new Document();

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("file9.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);

            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c3 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c4 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c5 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c6 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell c7 = new PdfPCell();
            String con = null;
            for (int i= 0;i<res.Length;i++)
            {
                List<String> col = new List<String>();

                foreach (string line in res[i].ToString().Split('|'))
                {
                    con = res[i];
                    col.Add(line);
                }

                string[] columns = col.ToArray();

                    c1.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[0]));
                    c2.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[1]));
                    c3.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[2]));
                    c4.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[3]));
                    c5.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[4]));
                    c6.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[5]));
                    c7.AddElement(new Phrase(columns[6]));

                table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 }));



            }
            AddParagraph(doc, iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, _largeFont, table);
            AddParagraph(doc, iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, _largeFont, new Chunk(con));

            doc.Close();
        }

        private void AddParagraph(Document doc, int alignment, iTextSharp.text.Font font, iTextSharp.text.IElement content)
        {
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.SetLeading(0f, 1.2f);
            paragraph.Alignment = alignment;
            paragraph.Font = font;
            paragraph.Add(content);
            doc.Add(paragraph);
        }

        private Font _largeFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

    }
}
```

This is how my file looks now:

https://postimg.org/image/vbn3ui2qh/

Comment: I looked at your code, and I don't understand. Why are you doing this: `table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 }));` That doesn't make any sense, does it? Did you read any of the documentation? (Apparently not, otherwise you wouldn't use the `PdfPRow` object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is much too long. Reduce it to:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
for (int i= 0;i<res.Length;i++)
{
    List<String> col = new List<String>();
    foreach (string line in res[i].ToString().Split('|'))
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(line));
    }
}
document.Add(table);
```

As you can see, this is much shorter than what you have.

I don't understand why:

- You create `List<String> col` when all you need is to put `string` values in a table.
- You use the `PdfPRow` class to create the row. I am the #1 producer of iText documentation, and I haven't written any documentation that leads to believe you should use the `PdfRow` class.
- You put a `PdfPTable` inside a `Paragraph`. That isn't necessary. If you think it is, explain why you think so, and we'll explain how you can achieve what you want without using a `Paragraph`.